# How to add characters to a string between specific characters in bash?

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell, scripting

Right now I'm working on creating a script in linux bash shell that adds the word "-BACKUP" to a file name between certain points. For example, if I had a file/string called file1.txt I would want to add the "-BACKUP" between "file1" and ".txt" to make "file1-BACKUP.txt". How would I go about doing that? Would I use the `basename` command anywhere? In this situation, the extension and stem could be anything, not just what I gave as an example. All help is appreciated!

Comment: `f='file1.txt'; echo "${f/./-backup.}"`

Comment: I would like to insert the characters before the final '.' if there is a stem. If there is no stem then I would prefer if it did nothing.

Comment: @anubhava could you plz explain how your suggestion works?

Comment: `"${f/./-backup.}"` is doing a string replacement of DOT by `-backup.`

Answer (score 0):

Use the substring processing parameter expansion operator `%` to remove the suffix from the string, then append the new text. The variable must be enclosed in braces for substring processing parameter expansion to work.

```
var="file1.txt"

echo "${var%.txt}.BACKUP.txt"
```